# GitBash auto switch to develop branch after clone

Tags: git, branch, git-bash

I work in a microservices project where each microservice is a Spring Boot project on its own and developement goes to develop branch while master is the "production" branch.

by default git checks out the master branch after cloning a project.
It is frustrating and error prone having to do `git checkout develop` every time I clone a project or having to do

```
git stash   
git checkout develop   
git stash pop
```

eveytime I need to checkin code that I mistakenly implemented on the master branch.

Isn't there a way to configure git so that after cloning a project it checks out another branch automatically (ie. develop branch)?

I am looking for answers or ideas that can get me to answer myselft or maybe implement a script or  alias or anything  that can fix this problem. Because otherwise I'll have to turn to a visual git tool.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Git checks out whatever branch the remote repository has identified as the default branch...so if the remote repositories were configured with the `develop` branch as the default, you would be all set.

When you clone a repository, you can start with a branch other than the default by using the `--branch` (`-b`) flag:

```
git clone -b develop ....
```

You can set up a git alias for cloning your project's repositories with something like:

```
git config --global alias.dev 'clone -b develop'
```

Now if you run:

```
git dev https://remote/repo.git
```

You will be running:

```
git clone -b develop https://remote/repo.git
```